# bootstrap dropdown works only half of the time

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

If it works and I click another link then it stops working. If I click again the same link it starts working again. I have included the CDNs up top and Script at the bottom. I don't think that it has anything to do with the if statement (as it would hide the whole navbar).

```
<!-- nav -->
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href='' > dempow</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      </li>
    </ul> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Cont<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Ieşire', destroy_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Editare Detalii Cont', edit_user_registration_path %></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <% end %> 
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

--- I just observed that it does not work at all when collapsed.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem and the answer below does not fix it

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found this dropdown example on the http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns docs. Try removing data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class.
Heres what it looks like http://www.bootply.com/hNlJt7c3hj

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem as the OP and this did not solve it, any other ideas as to why this would happen??